# How to read content of the file and save it to string type variable? Why there is empty space?

Tags: c++, file

This is how I get the name of the file from the command line and open a file and save the content of the file line by line to a string. All the procedures works fine except three empty spaces at the beginning of the file. Is anyone can say why these empty spaces occurred and how can I ignore them?

```
string filename = "input.txt";

char *a=new char[filename.size()+1];
a[filename.size()]=0;
memcpy(a,filename.c_str(),filename.size());

ifstream fin(a);
if(!fin.good()){
    cout<<" = File does not exist ->> No File for reading\n";
    exit(1);
}
string s;
while(!fin.eof()){
    string tmp;
    getline(fin,tmp);
    s.append(tmp);
    if(s[s.size()-1] == '.')
    {
        //Do nothing
    }
    else
    {
        s.append(" ");
    }
        cout<<s<<endl;
```

Comment: What does the beginning of the file you're reading look like?  Does it have blank lines?

Comment: This is the file I read :   THE  
And this is the output  :   ���THE

Comment: `cout << "s" << endl;` was meant to be `cout << s << endl;`, right?

Comment: Yes you right. just edited

Answer (score 1):

The most probable cause is that your file is encoded in something else than ASCII. It contains a bunch of unprintable bytes and the string you on the screen is the result of your terminal interpreting those bytes. To confirm this, print the size of `s` after the reading is done. It should be larger than the number of characters you see on the screen.

Other issues:

```
string filename = "input.txt";
char *a=new char[filename.size()+1];
a[filename.size()]=0;
memcpy(a,filename.c_str(),filename.size());
ifstream fin(a);
```

is quite an overzealous way to go about it. Just write `ifstream fin(a.c_str());`, or simply `ifstream fin(a);` in C++11.

Next,

```
while(!fin.eof()){
```

is almost surely a bug. `eof()` does not tell if you the next read will succeed, only whether the last one reached `eof` or not. Using it this way will tipically result in last line seemingly being [read twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong#comment18550194_5605125).

Always, always, check for success of a read operation before you use the result. That's idiomatically done by putting `getline` in the loop condition: `while (getline(fin, tmp))`

Comment: My file is a notepad and I typed inside it myself, even if the file is empty I get three question marks at the beginning.... I change it to c_str() and eof() but still I get same thing.

Comment: @Bernard Show a complete compilable program then ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org)), along with the contents of the file.

Comment: That was complete program but you only need to put it in int main() { and } and put a file in same directory to run this.

Comment: @Bernard Your issue is [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), I'd say. The fact that you "typed it in notepad" is... not very relevant. As said, you've got it encoded in Unicode or UTF-8. Select "Ansi" from the dropdown list when you save the file.